# How to randomly replace a string in a list based on another list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, replace

I have the following problem, where I have a list of strings and I want to replace certain words randomly based on another list.

my original list looks like this:

```
original_list = [['Bananas' 'are' 'boring' 'and' 'too' 'sweet'],
['Why','can', 'we','get','apples','but','no','blueberries'],
['this','is','not','good','for','eat','some','grapes'],
['have','you','ever','tried','to','buy','all','the','different','apples']]
```

this is the list of words I would like to randomly replace in `original_list`:

```
orginal_words = ['Bananas','apples','grape']
```

and this is the list of words I would like to randomly select instead for the `original_words`:

```
replacement_words = ['popcorn','juice','chocolate','chips','cake','sweets']
```

I figured out a way to do this for an individual word, but I'm not sure how to make it more efficient based on lists:

```
from random import shuffle
shuffle(replacement_words)
for el in replacement_words:
    for test_str in original_list:
        test_str = test_str.replace('Bananas', el)
        print("String after random replacement : " + str(test_str))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pick randomly `replacement_words` list by index, using:

```
ind = random.randint(0, len(replacement_words))
```

Also, it doesn't guarantee the uniqueness of elements. You can generate list well in advance and make:

```
for new_word, old_word in zip(original_list, replacement_words_indices):
  # Do replacement here
```

The algo will be linear, not quadratic.

Comment: That's crazy; just do a random shuffle of `replacement_words` and then loop over the result.

Comment: @tripleee, It's a possibility. I didn't claim that my answer is better or more efficient—only an alternative.